# how to replace master branch in git, partially, from another branch

Tags: git

I have two branches in my git repo:
1. Master
2. FeatureBranch
**FeatureBranch** was created from **Master**, and all the changes are made into a project solution within a specific subfolder, e.g. **FeatureBranchDir**. after the branch created, some other devs still go on to make commits to **Master**, but all changes are in other folders.
Now, i want to replace the **FeatureBranchDir** in **Master** branch with the ones from **FeatureBranch**.
What's the best practice to do this?
Please note: **FeatureBranchDir** exist in both **Master**and **FeatureBranch**, and git merge is not an option since i want the dir to be replaced rather than merge the two version. And also, i want to keep history of FeatureBranchDir from master. but i think that won't be a problem since the history was kept in FeatureBranch, right?

Comment: Is the FeatureBranchDir is the dir exist in master as well, Is it the fork from master or new dir you want to add from feature to master?

Comment: Can you just do a git merge?

Comment: I don't really understand situation. Why merge is not an option? Did you have any changes in FeatureBranchDir on Master **after**  FeatureBranch was created?

Comment: Also do you want to preserve history of FeatureBranchDir on master?

Comment: @running.t, yes, the dir in master also modified, but we want to ignore those after 'merge'

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the `FeatureBranchDir` in master with the one in FeatureBranch during a `git merge`. It is just in git terms is called a [merge](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge)(or you can do a [rebase](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Rebasing), if you want to beautify your log). And yes, the logs will be as is.

The reason you do a `git merge` is to merge the two branches (master & feature) together, as they have branched off, when you created a branch, and so must be brought together for the changes of one to sync with the other, according to Git. And it doesn't have anything to do with the file system.

Comment: What is `MasterDir` in your answer? Does it have something in common with `FeatureDir` on FeatureBranch?